# Slicing the image by coding

Tags: ios, uiimage, slice

I saw some apps which is something like a puzzle. It first asks to select an image, and slice them and put into 4x4 or 5x5 squares randomly. One square will be empty and user can rearrange them by slide the image to empty slot.

I know how to slide the image. But main task is how to slick them into smaller images?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Long discusses this in his article [Subduing `CATiledLayer`](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but I think it should work.

Load the image into a UIImageView of the size that want the slice to be, so lets use a 480x320  image as an example. Lets slice this into 9 parts, a 3x3 grid. That would make each piece 160x106 (roughly, 320 does not evenly divide by 3)

So create your UIImageView with the size 160x106, set the `image` property to your full-sized image. And set the image view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` so that the regions not in the view are clipped. I haven't tried it but I assume this would give you the top left corner of your grid, position 1,1.

Now here is where you make a choice depending on memory efficiency/performance, you will have to test which is best.

**Option 1**

Continue to do this for each slice, but set the UIImage's frame so that the correct portion of the image is being displayed and the rest is being clipped. So your frame for position 1,2 would look like `CGRectMake(106, 0, 106, 160)` for position 2,2 it would be `CGRectMake(106*2, 160, 106, 160)` and so forth.

This is result in the full image being loaded into memory 9 times, this may or may not be a problem. You will have to do some analysis on memory usage.

**Option 2**

Once you create your "slice" in the UIImageView, save that context off as a file that you will later load into appropriate UIImageViews.

The following code demonstrates one way to save a UIView's context to a UIImage.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size);
[[yourView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imageOfView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You would then save off this UIImage to disk with an appropriate name to be loaded into the appropriate slice later.